# How to mirror part of closed bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a complex asymmetric shaped bezier curve. I'd need to mirror or flip one third of it but I can't figure it out. Here is a sample file and image that explains what I am trying to do:
[image]

Here is link to sample file:
https://www.upload.ee/files/13612937/flipping.zip.html
and another link
https://uploadfiles.net/ST6/flipping.zip

Comment: so you could delete a part of your curve, duplicate the one that you want to flip, then SY-A to flip on Y, then fill the gap between the 2 parts?

Comment: How do you delete a part of curve? The knot is deleted but there is still curve there when I try deleting a bezier knot in edit mode?

Comment: select 2 vertices then X > Delete Segments

Comment: Thanks, I never figured out why deleting segments did basically nothing when I had just one vert selected. I try it now.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, if you want make a solution post about your delete segment tip and mirror and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the vertices you want and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Segments*:

[image]

Select the remaining vertices, duplicate and press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> in order to mirror:

[image]

At the end, fill the gaps with some <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]